# Add and remove launcher icons from command line

Tags: 12.10, launcher, icons

I am building an Ubuntu 12.10 VM using Vagrant and Chef, and I want to control which icons initially appear in the launcher.

Specifically I want to clear out all of the initial launcher icons, just leaving the Start icon and Nautilous, then add icons for a couple of applications I'm installing with Chef.

Adding the icons I can probably handle from other posts, but how can I remove existing icons using only the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- To view the current ones:

  ```
  gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
  ```

  would output something like:

  ```
  ['nautilus-home.desktop', 'chromium-browser.desktop', 'gnome-system-monitor.desktop']
  ```
- To add new entry, say `vlc`, add its .desktop file ie. `vlc.desktop` as:

  ```
  gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['nautilus-home.desktop', 'chromium-browser.desktop', 'gnome-system-monitor.desktop', 'vlc.desktop']"
  ```

*(those included in the value string "[... ... ...]" will be show up in the launcher. You can use this to add or remove the launchers of your choice.)*

- To reset to the default values:

  ```
  gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
  ```

Comment: so could I remove the ones I don't want in the same way? `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['nautilus-home.desktop', 'vlc.desktop']"`

Comment: yes you can.. exclude the .desktop files of those you want to remove..

Comment: corrected the typo... to add it's `set` not `get`...

Comment: How do I refresh the launcher?  I removed some launchers, but they still show.