# How can I either lock items in the launcher OR restore a set of items in the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I admin a batch of Ubuntu 14.04 desktop machines in a public library (they are diskless and boot via DRBL). Sometime users (I'm guessing kids) remove icons from the launcher. I want to either prevent that or have a simple means of restoring the launcher's state (eg via an autostart script).  How can I do that?  I found this (old) thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2023390, but there are no specific details and I can't seem to figure out how to use dconf.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/409086/add-and-remove-launcher-icons-from-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current configuration of most areas of the desktop can be viewed using [Dconf Editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/), or using the command line utility `gsettings`:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

Example output:

```
['application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'application://unity-control-center.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'application://gnome-terminal.desktop', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']
```

You can then use to restore it to that state *(try removing things from the launcher, you can see any changes)*, using the `set` option *(note the quotes `"`)* with the output from the `get` command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'application://unity-control-center.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'application://gnome-terminal.desktop', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']"
```

So if you get the launcher in the state you want, and use the `get` to get it, you can then set it back later with the `set` command. You could add this in `gnome-session-properties` and then it should set itself on login:

[image]

**See also:** https://askubuntu.com/a/367590/178596