# I want to learn how Unity works (documentation/command line tutorials)

Tags: unity, documentation

*some people are marking this question as duplicate of some other question(which are I looked up, not helpful. since it is just explainig how to use unity, not technical/command line documentation) which is not right*

---

I want to learn how unity works. for example, instead of dragging application shortcut from dash to launcher, how do I do it using terminal?

how to make application shortcut ?

I can lock an application to the launcher by GUI but how to do it from terminal?

How an I add a mounted partition icon automatically if I mount it from a folder other than `/media`?

---

these are just examples, I dont meant just to learn these but unity all-together

Comment: that is a wide range of question :) probably better to split up.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I gave examples, my question is broader -from where to get unity documentation

Comment: I think this is a good question, but most open source projects are only partially documented, and you'll learn the full picture of Unity as you attempt to solve each of those questions one a time.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to learn how unity works. for example, instead of dragging application shortcut from dash to launcher, how do I do it using terminal?

[Add and remove launcher icons from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409086)

> How to make an application shortcut?

[How to add programs to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224004)

> I can lock an application to the launcher by GUI but how to do it from terminal?

Same as 1st question: [Add and remove launcher icons from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409086)

> How can I add a mounted partition icon automatically if I mount it from a folder other than /media?

[How to customize/label the hard drive icons in the launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70867)

Overall technical questions:

Go to the [wiki, here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity). It says:

> The wiki documentation is targeting technical users, if you want to get an overview of Unity you might be interested.

There is also (of course) the [Ubuntu Documentation](http://help.ubuntu.com) site (please, please upvote [Jacob's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/555047/186134), as that is what reminded me of it), and a [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ubuntu%20documentation) does give some good results:

[image]

Comment: this answer helps :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept if it helped fully!

Comment: ill but after some time, let lookup those links properly

Answer (score 3):

One would almost forget the obvious:

A perfect starting point for a wide range of subjects is this [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/) site.

See for example what happens if you enter *launcher command line* in the searchbox...
I almost forgot how much information I got there in the past.

[image]

It links to man pages, matching results on Askubuntu, official documentation etc, etc. Too much to mention.

Answer (score -1):

The only one I can help you with is the shortcut. You could use ln -s to make a symbolic link via terminal to wherever you want. That should function the same way as shortcut.

I'd imagine there's some configuration file that's dynamically updated for the launcher on the left for things you add, remove, or lock. I have no idea where that is though.

I'd probably just try a symbolic link for tricking Unity into thinking there's something mounted at /media or /mnt to get the icon as well.

Comment: Think this is wrong... the first part definitely is.

Comment: I'm kind of new to Linux still, can you explain to me why a symbolic link won't work for a shortcut?

Comment: Because he wants a link to an application. What would you suggest linking to for this shortcut? There is nothing (other than .desktop files, and you can copy them).

Comment: The application in /usr/bin/? That's all I was thinking though.

Comment: Don't think that works...